# How to see the original path of a file in the recycle bin?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recycle-bin

When right clicking a file in the Recycle Bin I can't see what file path that file originally had. Since Windows must know the original file path (how else would it be able to restore the file to it's original location?) there must be a way to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to "detailed view" inside the recycle bin folder, one of the columns show will be the Original Location column.

[image]

Comment: Great, this was much more easy than expected. Thank you.